# R plugin for SPSS

Tags: r, spss

Can anyone tell me how can I integrate the R plugin for SPSS version 17?? I need to do some statistics using the R plugin for SPSS, unfortunately I can't find the plugin on the internet, so can anyone help me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about troubleshooting SPSS. Unfortunately with the purchase by IBM SPSS has taken away some of the older plug ins. This [recent post on the SPSS nabble list-serve](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/matching-versions-of-R-and-SPSS-td5717805.html) states it is not available anymore for versions pre 18.

Answer (score 1):

Check this website, it has a detailed explanation of how should you do:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Ffaq_plugins.htm

Under Sharing, you can find Download for IBM SPSS Statistics, and you can find related downloads from there.

Comment: I once looked into that one, but I never successfully did anything with it...

Comment: check the edit.